# To set minimum order amount to customer who have already purchased

Tags: magento

Initially i set minimum order amount as $1000. But now i want to allow the customer who have already purchased only,to make reorder with below Minimum Order i.e)that customer can reorder with $500.

i don't know "is it possible?" If anybody know, please help me guys

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Minimum ReOrder Amount, how can I fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109930/minimum-reorder-amount-how-can-i-fix-this)


Please check it!

Answer (score 0):

It`s not possible to reduce for the amount of existing customer.